# JLabel format a Tab

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I want to use a Tab in a JLabel. Why is my code not working?

```
String tab = String.format("%c", '\t');
label.setText("Total:" + tab + total + " CHF");
```

Comment: JLabels don't do tabs

Comment: Is there an alternative?

Comment: Yes. Use multiple JLabels, not a single one, and appropriate layout managers. All will depend on just what GUI you're trying to create, something we know nothing about currently.

Comment: An alternative would be to use JLabel label = new JLabel("Total:&emsp;"+total+"CHF"); If I'm not wrong JLabel accept Html in it